# MySQL max packet error centOS 6.3

Tags: mysql, linux

Just tried to import a .SQL backup off vBulletin forums.

And after a few minutes, Im getting this error:

http://gyazo.com/1b50e0f20cdec58ebe5722965857595c.png

Why is this happening?

I assume I have to increase the packet size, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `my.cnf` config file you can configure that value. There might be a setting already which you can edit. If not, add it. See the MySQL manual for detailed information.

However, this is less a StackOverflow question, but something for ServerFault. See this question there: https://serverfault.com/questions/244818/setting-max-allowed-packet-commandline-vs-config